# Technology Used for building this site

Tags: support, stack-overflow, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

What are all the technologies used at the frontend and the backend of this website?

Comment: I know the search isn't that great here, but it was pretty easy to find this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/10370#10370

Comment: The search for this particular question topic is fantastic.

Comment: extremely dupe... just like zoredache said.

Answer (score 1):

Tinkertoys and lego.  They totally rag on kinex and brio.

Comment: It's actually LEGO®, apparently, even in plural. Or so I'm told. :)

Comment: Igot out of the shower this morning AND HAD THE EXACT SAME THOUGHT.  First order of business was to take care of that.  Of course, I blame it on those crazy denmarkians and their poor grasp of English plurals.  Don't bother me with the fact that it's actually denmarkish.  (Actually my sister in law speaks Danish and has been there for a few years at a time a few times before.  She says it's quite a lovely country.)  LEGOS.

Comment: LEGO is the name of the company - the product is a LEGO brick. It'd be like referring to the PS3 as a Sony, and pluralizing by calling it Sonys, rather than PS3s.

Comment: I suppose nobody here says, "pass me a Kleenex," either. Everyone says, "pass me a Kleenex®-brand facial tissue?" :)

Comment: I make Xerox brand copies, and I never google something - I always use a google search to find something.